# collecting multiple maximum values

Tags: loops, lisp, max, common-lisp

I have a list of elements. Each element is structured as followed:

```
('symbol "string" int-score)
```

An example list:

```
(list (list 'object1 "wabadu" 0.5)
      (list 'object2 "xezulu" 0.6)
      (list 'object1 "yebasi" 0.5)
      (list 'object1 "tesora" 0.2))
```

I want to retrieve the maximum values for a specific symbol. When I search with the symbol `object2`, I should get back:

```
('object2 "xezulu" 0.6)
```

If I search with `object1`, I should get back:

```
(('object1 "wabadu" 0.5) ('object1 "yebasi" 0.5))
```

I want to collect all the highest elements of a specific object.  What I can do is this: assume that the above list is the list used below and that I'm searching for `object1`. I can retrieve all elements of a specific object:

```
(loop for element in list
     when (equal 'object1 (first element))
     collect element)
```

I can also retrieve one highest element of the list:

```
(loop for element in list
     when (equal 'object1 (first element))
     maximize (third element))
```

However, this will only return one element. What I want is *all* maximum elements. I've tried some combinations with `collect` and `maximize`, but my knowledge on the syntax is little. Is there a way to collect all the highest elements in a ‘simple’ function?

Comment: Hmm... The first example for [iterate](http://common-lisp.net/project/iterate/) seems to be meant to do what you're trying to do... I tried briefly, though, and failed to get iterate to actually work for me, so... not treating this as an answer, for now.  If I figure it out, I'll post one; others are encouraged to beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by `loop`ing through the list once for selecting all the sublists with the right first elements and determining the maximum (you can use `into` to let `loop` accumulate multiple values), and then a second `loop` in the `finally` clause go through the selection and now select only those with the maximum score:

```
(loop for triple in *l*
      for (key nil score) = triple
      when (eq key 'object1)
        collect triple into selection
        and maximize score into max-score
      finally (return (loop for triple in selection
                            when (eql (third triple) max-score)
                              collect triple)))
```

**Edit**: Alternatively, instead of a second loop, the `delete` function can be used here quite concisely:

```
(loop for triple in *l*
      for (key name score) = triple
      when (eq key 'object1)
        collect triple into selection
        and maximize score into max-score
      finally (return (delete max-score selection
                              :test #'/=
                              :key #'third)))
```

Comment: In the end I choose for your solution, I found it a good one.

Answer (score 2):

A sketch of a LOOP-based version:

```
(defun mymax (target list &aux result max)
  (loop for (item name value) in list
        when (eql item target)
        do (cond ((or (null result)
                      (> value max))
                  (setf result (list (list item name value))
                        max value))
                 ((= value max)
                  (push (list item name value) result))))
  result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create a `hash-table` with the keys being the symbols and the values being arranged in the way `(maximum . (list of strings corresponding to maximum))`

```
(let ((data (list (list 'object1 "wabadu" 0.5)
                  (list 'object2 "xezulu" 0.6)
                  (list 'object1 "yebasi" 0.5)
                  (list 'object1 "tesora" 0.2))))
  (loop
     :with table := (make-hash-table)
     :for (item string num) :in data :do
     (destructuring-bind (&optional max strings)
         (gethash item table)
       (cond
         ((or (null max) (< max num))
          (setf (gethash item table) (list num (list string))))
         ((= max num)
          (setf (cdr strings) (cons string (cdr strings))))))
     :finally (return table)))

;; #<HASH-TABLE {1005C6BE93}>
;; --------------------
;; Count: 2
;; Size: 16
;; Test: EQL
;; Rehash size: 1.5
;; Rehash threshold: 1.0
;; [clear hashtable]
;; Contents: 
;; OBJECT1 = (0.5 ("wabadu" "yebasi")) [remove entry]
;; OBJECT2 = (0.6 ("xezulu")) [remove entry]
```

I think your life would be later easier with this hash table then with the data structure you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

The `maximize` returns only one element. You can sort all the list by the 3rd component and then gets the front one(s). Like this:

```
;;; suppose a copy of the data is stored in l

;; get all 'object1 and sort them
(setf l (sort (remove-if-not
                (lambda (x) (equal (first x) 'object1)) l)
              #'> :key #'third))
;; remove the ones with smaller value than the first one
(setf l (remove-if
          (lambda (x) (< (third x) (third (first l)))) l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Abstract your data to create basic building blocks; combine building blocks into your needed functionality:

```
(defun make-foo (type name score)
   (list type name score))

(defun foo-type (foo) (elt foo 0))
;; ...

(defun make-foos (&rest foos)
  foos)

(defun foos-find-if (foos predicate)
  ;; return all foos satisfying predicate
  )

(defun foos-maximize (foos orderer)
  ;; return the maximum foo (any one)
  )

(defun foos-find-if-maximized (foos)
  (foos-find-if foos 
    (let ((max (foos-maximize foos #'foo-score)))
      (lambda (foo)
        (= (foo-score max) (foo-score foo))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach by first saving `symbol-list` that only contains the lists with the search object. Then we can easily get the maximum value and remove those lists with a smaller value.

```
(defun foo (symbol list)
  (let* ((symbol-list (remove-if-not #'(lambda (l) (eq (first l) symbol))
                       list))
         (max (apply #'max (mapcar #'third symbol-list))))
    (remove-if-not #'(lambda (l) (= (third l) max))
     symbol-list)))
```

We can call it: `(foo 'object1 l)`

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, if you are really wanting to boil down a list of things into a single result, there should be a nice way to do this with reduce.

And there is:

```
(defun collect-maxima-by-third (list)
  (reduce
   #'(lambda (max-list next-element)
       (let ((max-value (third (first max-list)))
             (next-value (third next-element)))
         (cond ((< max-value next-value)
                (list next-element))
                ((= max-value next-value)
                 (cons next-element max-list))
                (t max-list)))) ; the greater-than case
   (rest list)
   :initial-value (list (first list))))
```

It's not perfect, as if you give it an empty list it will give you a list containing an empty list instead of just an empty list, but you can easily add a case for this if you think that will happen often.

This type of technique (maybe not this exact example) is detailed in various texts on functional programming; some Haskell texts do a particularly good job (Learn You a Haskell comes to mind).